# awk: line 1: syntax error at or near >

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I'm getting this above syntax error and i can't decipher what is wrong with it. 
I'm trying to do a float value in BASH.

Hence i used this command called the `awk` to achieve the target.

```
while $empty; do
    empty=false
    echo -n "Price : "; read getPrice

#float value using awk
awk 'BEGIN{if ('$getPrice'>'0') exit 1}'
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    PRICE[$COUNT]=$getPrice;

else
    empty=true 
    echo "Please put in the correct price figure!"
fi

done
```

However, i got this error

> awk: line 1: syntax error at or near >

This error occured when i did not input any value into the `getPrice` variable. However, it's working fine when i input some value which is `>0`. After much deliberation, i still could not figure what is wrong with the syntax. Regards.

Comment: Apart from the awk issue, $COUNT will always evaluate to ""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get a syntax error in your Awk script is because when `$getPrice` is empty, then the script is actually just

```
BEGIN{if (>0) exit 1}
```

The proper way to import a shell variable into an Awk script as an Awk variable is by using `-v`:

```
awk -vprice="$getPrice" 'BEGIN { if (price > 0) exit 1 }'
```

I also had a look at the flow of contol in your script, and rather than using the `$empty` variable, you could just exit the loop when a correct price has been entered:

```
while true; do
    read -p 'Price : ' getPrice

    # compare float value using awk
    if awk -vprice="$getPrice" 'BEGIN { if (price <= 0) exit(1) }'
    then
      PRICE[$COUNT]="$getPrice"
      break
    fi

    echo 'Please put in the correct (positive) price figure!' >&2
done
```

**Additional detail after comments:**

The user should be alerted about invalid input if the value entered is not a number or if it's negative.  We can test the inputted value for characters that are not supposed to be there (anything other than the digits 0 through to 9 and the decimal point):

```
while true; do
    read -p 'Price : ' getPrice

    if [[ ! "$getPrice" =~ [^0-9.] ]] && \
        awk -vprice="$getPrice" 'BEGIN { if (price <= 0) exit(1) }'
    then
        PRICE[$COUNT]="$getPrice"
        break
    fi

    echo 'Please put in the correct (positive) price figure!' >&2
done
```

Comment: it seems to return me a `bc: invalid option -- 'e'` error.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan Ah, you're on Linux.  Use `bc <<<"$getPrice > 0"` instead of `bc -e "$getPrice > 0" -e quit` (which works on BSD).

Comment: i seems to get a syntax error when i use the `bc <<<"$getPrice > 0"` code. May i ask what does `<<<` do?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan It's a "here-string". It sends the string inte the command on standard input. I'm starting to think that using `bc` is a bad idea. Partly because of compatibility reasons, but it also suffers from the same problem as your original script if `$getPrice` is empty. My Awk solution should still be good though.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. however i would like to ask, is it possible to do two different check during a single awk script? I'm trying to check if the value is positive and if the user insert any input apart from numbers. like if the user enter a letter, it will prompt any error msg.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan Updated. I will not modify this further.

Answer (score 2):

If `$getPrice` is empty, this line

```
awk 'BEGIN{if ('$getPrice'>'0') exit 1}'
```

becomes

```
awk 'BEGIN{if (>0) exit 1}'
```

which is probably not what you intended.  You could use one of the shell substitutions to provide a non-empty value (though mixing shell and awk like this still is not recommended practice):

```
awk 'BEGIN{if ('${getPrice:-0}'>'0') exit 1}'
```

It's better to pass variables to awk using the `-v` option (but that's actually a different question, answered several times).

Comment: i tried using the method you gave above, but however if i did not input any value into the price, it doesn't prompt the error message. Instead it continues to run the next function.

Comment: That's expected since the comparison is "0>0" (always false).  You'll have to decide what the expected behavior of the script should be, and how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing in `getPrice` then the `awk` code is

```
BEGIN{if (>0) exit 1}
```

which is totally invalid syntax. Guard against `getPrice` being empty (or better yet check that it appears to be a number of some sort).

Is `bash` actually a requirement? This would be easier in ZSH or really any language with floating point support:

```
bash-3.2$ exec zsh
% echo 3.14 | read x; [[ $x -gt 0 ]] && echo positive
positive
% exec tclsh
tclsh> set x [read stdin]
3.14
3.14

tclsh> if {$x > 0} { puts positive }
positive
tclsh>
```

Comment: yeah, apparently bash is a requirement. i just started learning how to do shell-scripting not long ago.